# Get a random user from server discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How do you pick a random user from a server that a bot is in?

For example, GiveawayBot randomly picks a user in a giveaway. How can I implement that but without having to click on a reaction for the giveaway?

Also an example, @r in a command in Minecraft.

Comment: 1) [check for recipients] (https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel) -> array of user in the channel, then you can just use a random generated number from 0 to N-1 user and pick the winner
2) I don't understand what are u asking actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Array.from(message.member.guild.members)**

This will get you an array of all members in a guild (with their id). I would recommend doing something else as it would take a lot of space to store larger servers in cache but it's up to you.

After doing so you can make a random number generator from 0 to the greatest amount and you will get an object of the user back when indexed, with the id as the identifier.

Comment: And how do I get the amount of people in my server?

Comment: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=memberCount